# Setting the location of Wakatime config files in Portable VS Code

Tags: settings, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, wakatime

When you set up Wakatime on Portable Visual Studio Code, it automatically puts the config files (`.wakatime.cfg`, `.wakatime.db`, `.wakatime.log`) in `C:/Users/<username>`. I would like these to be set in the `data` directory of the VS Code. When you start the VS Code in another computer, it prompts for Wakatime API key because the key was left in the other machine. How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 1):

In Wakatime's `extension.js`, this is explicitly specified in line 193 and 689 . I edited the second function to set the config files in `data/extensions` inside VS Code portable directory but would obviously be overwritten with updates. I just have to change it back after an update. Updates are less often than moving between machines so it will do for now.

```js
getWakaHome() {
        let home = process.env.WAKATIME_HOME;
        if (home) {
            return home;
        }
        else {
            return this.getUserHomeDir();
        }
    }
```

```js
 getUserHomeDir() {
        return process.env[Dependencies.isWindows() ? 'USERPROFILE' : 'HOME'] || '';
    }
```

change above to `getUserHomeDir()`

```js
 getUserHomeDir() {
        return 'data/extensions-data';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set an environment variable to specify where the wakatime files will be stored. Save this variable as `$WAKATIME_HOME`. It worked on Linux.

Click [here](https://github.com/wakatime/wakatime-cli/blob/develop/USAGE.md#usage) to see more.